# Reading a field from a JSON log in Splunk using SPATH

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am trying to read an attribute from a Splunk log that looks like this

```
context=context{version="1.1.2", id="123", userId=""}
```

I need to get count by version

My Splunk query :

```
index="$index" "$filterString" | spath input=context output=versionId path=version | stats count by versionId
```

The value of version is not being read correctly. Is the spath correct here?

Comment: what does your sample data actually look like?

Comment: that format is not JSON. JSON field names and values are separated by `:` and not `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spath` is the right command, but it only works with valid JSON strings.  The given string is considered invalid by jsonlint.com.

Here is a workaround that uses `rex` to extract the version ID.

```
index="$index" "$filterString"
| rex field=context "version=\\\"(?<versionId>[^\\\"]+)"
| stats count by versionId
```